# How can I install Indicator Synapse on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity

When I try to install Indicator Synapse on my computer, I used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

But it gives me an error `E: Unable to locate package indicator-synapse`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command on your terminal. Then It will be OK.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse
```

If you face problem with ubuntu 16.04, Then follow the following instruction:

**System Settings > Software&Updates > Other Software** > find and click noobslab/apps repository > Edit > change Distrbution value to "trusty". Then sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse. That's all.

You can also check this URL. Hope you will find the solution.

https://gist.github.com/brenopolanski/cb56125da4fede7a8abf